# C How to find coordinates located in a grid

Tags: c, linked-list, range, coordinates

I have a C program where a CSV file containing 8 x,y coordinates are inserted into a linked list.
Each of the 8 coordinates belongs in a 2x2 grid. There are 4 grids as seen in the picture below:

[image]

First I want my program to determine which coordinate belongs in which grid. Once I've determined that, for each grid, I want to sum all of the x-coordinates and y-coordinates. Then for each grid 1-4, I want to then print the total sum of the x coord and y coord.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

struct wake {
    double x, y;
    struct wake *next;
}*head;   

typedef struct {
    double x, y;
} grid_t;

typedef struct wake data;

void read_csv();
void gridSearch();
void maxNode();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    read_csv();
}

void read_csv() {
    // Opens the CSV datafile
    FILE *fp = fopen("data4.csv", "r");
    
    char buffer[MAX];
    struct wake** tail = &head;
    
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fp)) {
        data *node = malloc(sizeof(data));
        node->x = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        node->y = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
        
    }
    gridSearch();
    //maxNode();
}

void gridSearch() {  
    struct wake *current = head;  
    
    int i, j, gridnum = 0;
    grid_t (*grid)[2] = calloc(4, sizeof(grid_t[2][2]));
    //double min;
    
    if(head == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        while(current != NULL){
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if ((current->x >= -2+i*2) && (current->x <= -2+(i+1)*2)) {
                        if ((current->y >= -2+j*2) && (current->x <= -2+(j+1)*2)) {
                            printf("%lf\n", current->x);
                            grid[i][j].x += current->x;
                            grid[i][j].y += current->y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            current= current->next;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (j = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            gridnum++;
            printf("Sum of x coord in grid %d: %lf\n", gridnum, grid[i][j].x);
            printf("Sum of y coord in grid %d: %lf\n\n", gridnum, grid[i][j].y);
        }
    }   
}
```

When I run my program, nothing seems to happen. I've tried to figure out where the problem is but I'm stuck.

Here is the input CSV file:

```
-1,-1
-1,1.5
1,-1
1,1
-1.5,-1.5
-1,0.5
1.5,-1.5
0.5,0.5
```

Comment: I didn't get a useful answer.

Comment: Then you should improve that question. Why do you think, bothering people twice with same issue, will createbetter results?

Comment: Because when I posted my first question, I didn't get any useful help. All that user told me to do is debug my program, as if I didn't already do that before posting my question.

Comment: I would at least like a hint on where specifically I should look or an explanation on why my program might not be working correctly.

Comment: @daf debug your program to see why it doesn’t reach your printf.

Comment: Could you tell me where I should debug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C How to find and group coordinates located in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646104/c-how-to-find-and-group-coordinates-located-in-a-grid)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAX 200

struct data
{
    double x, y;
    data* next;
}*head;


struct grid_t
{
    double x, y;
};

void read_csv();
void gridSearch();

void read_csv()
{
    
    FILE* fp = fopen("data.cvs", "r");

    char buffer[MAX];
    data** tail = &head;

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fp))
    {
        data* node = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
        node->x = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        node->y = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
    }
    gridSearch();

    fclose(fp);
}

void gridSearch()
{    
    grid_t(*grid)[2] = (grid_t(*)[2])calloc(2*2, sizeof(grid_t));


    //Init  
    data *current = head;

    while (current)
    {
        double x = current->x;
        double y = current->y;
        current = current->next;

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {            
            if(x >= -2 + i * 2)
            if(x <= -2 + (i + 1) * 2)
            if(y >= -2 + j * 2)
            if(y <= -2 + (j + 1) * 2)
            {
                grid[j][i].x += x;
                grid[j][i].y += y;
            }
                    
        }
            
            
    }

    //print
    int num = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        num++;
        printf("Sum x coord in grid %d: %lf\n", num, grid[j][i].x);
        printf("Sum y coord in grid %d: %lf\n\n", num, grid[j][i].y);
    }
 
}
```